Como puedo imprimir vocales con tildes en una impresora termica con ESC POS ASCII?
estoy trabajando con impresoras termicas con C#, utilizando un dll de la marca SEWOO con código ASCII de Escape. El problema con el que me encuentro es que necesito imprimir vocales con tildes, pero al ingresarlas como string e imprimirlas aparecen caracteres especiales como signos de interrogacion, simbolos de mayor e igual, etc.
Mi pregunta es como puedo imprimir vocales con tildes. Muchas gracias amigos.
Dejo parte de mi codigo.
private static string strCenter = "\x1B\x61\x31";
private static string strLeft = "\x1B\x61\x30";
private static string strRight = "\x1B\x61\x32";
private static string strDouble = "\x1B\x21\x20"; // Horizontal Double
private static string strBold = "\x1B\x45\x01"; // BOLDEST
private static string strNormal = "\x1B\x21\x02";
private static string strUnderline = "\x1b\x2d\x02";
private static string separator = strUnderline + "                                        \r\n";

string voucher = "";
voucher += strCenter + strNormal;
voucher += "áéíóú \r\n";
voucher += "aeióu \r\n\r\n";


Seguramente hay algo que se llama "code page" y que se debe poder configurar en tu impresora, el clasico es el CP_850. Por ejemplo: https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1372206/Sewoo-Lk-P-Series.html?page=5
